# Binary Conversion Results In 00000000000

Tags: php, security, binary, hex

I'm testing some of my code that generates a passcode:

```
<?php
//8076?
$key = '8076e852267ecefe2a80c76b66ba8ca99fb7874fa5556e8b64f4707003f4aed0';

$a = time() . $key;
print "a = $a" . PHP_EOL;
$b = sprintf('%b', $a);                            
print "b = $b" . PHP_EOL;
$totp = hash('sha3-256', $b);
print "totp = $totp" . PHP_EOL;

$x = gmp_init(0);
$y = gmp_init(1);
for ($i = strlen($totp) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--, $y = gmp_mul($y, 16))
  $x = gmp_add($x, gmp_mul($y, hexdec($totp[$i])));
print "x = $x" . PHP_EOL;

print sprintf('%08d', gmp_strval(gmp_mod($x, '100000000')));
print PHP_EOL;
```

The results are:

```
a = 16407820138076e852267ecefe2a80c76b66ba8ca99fb7874fa5556e8b64f4707003f4aed0
b = 0
totp = f9e2eaaa42d9fe9e558a9b8ef1bf366f190aacaa83bad2641ee106e9041096e4
x = 113026826332749616999480801584179790214435636530758034338031008093509348529892
48529892
```

**Why is b = 000000...?**

I need to have a different passcode every time this key is used to generate it. I know this is stupid, a random number would work and be just as "secure". Security people are making me do this. I'm a software engineer.

There is something weird about this hex number. I get a good result for other values. For example $key = '3a8b9846009b54bb7a11e900e9b50000a6e14da4c4c2ef49f4016c326c339694' works fine.

Comment: With a key in code (I presume you are posting a test key, *right*?), no explanation of the protocol (or reference to), and using things like `time()` instead of a secure random number generator, that code would be heading for the bin if I had reviewed it. And as a programmer I would have raised hell about the variable names as well.

Comment: The time doesn't make it "random" it just makes the passcode different the next time it is used. Complaining about variable names is ridiculous. It's not real code anyway, just temporary scratch testing. Who cares where the "key" comes from? (It is decrypted from a database table)

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `printf()`? What does `%b` do?

Comment: You might have misunderstood what security people asked. You are reinventing the wheel, and you really shouldn't. What you want to achieve is described in RFCs 4226 and 6238, and there are well reviewed PHP [implementations](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/otphp). Also note that the _only_ useful advice (especially wrt `time()`) you received so far was by Maarten above.

Comment: The security guys told me to stick a timestamp at the end of it. Thanks for the link to PHP implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You're formatting the string `$a` as a binary number which doesn't make sense, you want to convert it. You need to use [pack](https://www.php.net/pack) and then convert that binary value to a string or integer or leave it as is, whatever you need.

Comment: No, sprint('%b', $str) "converts" it to a binary value representation which is what I want. Same thing as the function convert_base($x, 10, 2). I don't understand the pack() function. I just want to know why b = 0.

Comment: ok you are right. base_convert messes up too in all cases. So I've got to go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

This works now. (The hex string does not contain valid hex values so I used each character)

```
<?php

//$key = '8076e852267ecefe2a80c76b66ba8ca99fb7874fa5556e8b64f4707003f4aed0';
//$key = '3a8b9846009b54bb7a11e900e9b50000a6e14da4c4c2ef49f4016c326c339694';
$key = '145bfea3b819bee905b5d5295338964150c489789a9228f2e981b189de5cbbee';

$a = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($key); $i++)
   $a .= decbin(ord($key[$i]));
$a .= decbin(time());
print "a = $a" . PHP_EOL;
$totp = hash('sha3-256', $a);
print "totp = $totp" . PHP_EOL;

$x = gmp_init(0);
$y = gmp_init(1);
for ($i = strlen($totp) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--, $y = gmp_mul($y, 16))
  $x = gmp_add($x, gmp_mul($y, hexdec($totp[$i])));
print "x = $x" . PHP_EOL;

print sprintf('%08d', gmp_strval(gmp_mod($x, '100000000')));
print PHP_EOL;
```